# `dayjs()` is not defaulting to local time, how can I default dayjs() to be local?

Tags: dayjs

From [The documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/utc#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Day.,()%20instead%20of%20dayjs()%20.), it states, `By default, Day.js parses and displays in local time.`. I live in New Zealand with GMT +12 or +13 depending on daylight savings. When creating a `dayjs()` with the following `dayjs('2024-02-18')`, the result is, `Sat, 17 Feb 2024 11:00:00 GMT`. These days do not match up. I am looking for `dayjs(...)` to default to local time as stated on the documentation. Could anyone assist me on why is it not working as expected?